# Unknown error when attempting to build nextjs app

Tags: next.js, vercel

I get an error that I don't understand when I try to build my next js project.

index.js :

```
  import FeaturedPosts from "@/components/home-page/Featured-Posts";
import axios from "axios";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import Hero from "../components/home-page/Hero";


export default function HomePage({postList}) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Toaster />
      <Hero />
      <FeaturedPosts postList={postList} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/posts")
 return{ props: {
    postList: res?.data 
  }}
}
```

Error:

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from. Referenced from: /vercel/path0/.eslintrc.json
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
info  - Generating static pages (0/6)
info  - Generating static pages (1/6)
info  - Generating static pages (2/6)
```

I thought that it could be due to not having access to environment variables but, but taking them out of.env didn't change anything.

Comment: Please post the error in form of code here also your index.js code

Comment: No errors appear in my terminal or in the console when I load the page in development.

Comment: Is your http://localhost:3000/api/posts live during build time?

Comment: as far as I can tell yes, I am not running it when I'm building and it is accessible beforehand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using getStaticProps instead of getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you are calling   const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/posts") which is not live yet and you are returning the data without checking if it's available or not. When returing the props from getStaticProps do it as such:

```
return { 
  props: {
    postList: res?.data 
  },
  notFound: !res?.data,
}
```

You can also manually adding the props to see if it works without calling the api and later when you deploy it you can change the url. I suggest adding a url variable in url env so that you can easily switch between url when in production/development.

Comment: should I add not found to props for the component?

Comment: no this notFound is only a return property from getStaticProps, if no data was found during build time, you will get a page404 instead. Check this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#notfound

Comment: unfortunately this does not work :(, I will edit the post with two errors before that I thought werent important